# Getting absolute elevation from WMS raster tiles

Tags: raster, geoserver, wms, legend

When I use `GetMap` on a raster layer of a WMS GeoServer, the color scale adjusts automatically, so the scale is relative to the retrieved content of the requested area.

How do I extract numerically the absolute altitude/elevation ?

Alternatively, is there a way to tell the WMS server (GeoServer) to provide the absolute values ?

Comment: Use a WCS to access real data, or configure WMS to give real data values through a GetFeatureInfo request

Comment: Indeed both WCS (for a subset of pixels) and WMS:GetFeatureInfo (for a single pixel) do the job, thanks.